# Facebook authentication redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-authentication

I would like to use facebook Client-side authentication without the JS SDK to avoid popup. I try many ways many differences code but nothing work for many hours please help.
here my code

```
FB.init({
    appId  : appId,
    status : true,  // check login status
    cookie : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : false, // parse XFBML
    channel : 'http://fb.spot-the-differences.com/index.php',
    oauth : true
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        ...
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {            
    top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + 
    appId + "&redirect_uri='" +
    encodeURIComponent('http://fb.spot-the-differences.com') +
    "'&scope=read_friendlists,publish_actions,publish_stream,email&esponse_type=token";
});
```

I try add /index.php , change url to ip address try many codes but it always error

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.
```

**Facebook basic setting**

```
Site URL: http://fb.spot-the-differences.com/
Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/spot-the-differences
Canvas URL: http://fb.spot-the-differences.com/
Secure Canvas URL: https://fb.spot-the-differences.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
appId + "&redirect_uri='" +
encodeURIComponent('http://fb.spot-the-differences.com') +
"'&scope=…";
```

This will get you something like `&redirect_uri='http…` inside of the final URL.

The `'` is of course nonsense there – remove it!