# redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, scribe

I am using Scribe API for facebook sign functionality, but getting following error after submitting the facebook authentication url.

```
callback_url = http://localhost:18080/example/pub/social/facebook/signup/step2

OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(FacebookApi.class)
                .apiKey(apiKey).apiSecret(apiSecret)
                .scope("email")
                .callback(callbackUrl).build();

String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);

return "redirect:" + map.get("AUTHORIZATION_URL");

OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(FacebookApi.class)
                .apiKey(apiKey).apiSecret(apiSecret).build();
Verifier verifierObj = new Verifier(verifier);
        //String s = getAccesstoken(verifier);

Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifierObj)
```

I am getting below error @ last line

Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"error":{"message":"redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.","type":"OAuthException","code":191}}'

Settings n facebook app :

```
**Website with Facebook Login** : http://localhost:18080/example/
App domain : localhost
```

Kindly let me know if I am wrong anywhere...New to scribe and facebook platform.

Thanks
Raj

Comment: have you got an answer????? #user1989933

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook authentication redirect\_uri isn't an absolute URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108638/facebook-authentication-redirect-uri-isnt-an-absolute-uri)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you include https or http in front of the `redirect_uri`. And make sure you refer to it as `redirect_uri`.

Answer (score -1):

the callback_url is diferente of site with facebook login, change your url of site with facebook login to same to your callback_url.

Be careful with apps in to localhost, always try using one server for tests.

sorry for my poor english